# mod_rewrite: redirect `x -> /legacy/x` if file _does not exist_ in `/` but _does exist_ in `/legacy/`

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

For over 10 years I uploaded all sorts of files to the *root* of my webserver.

```
/
  oldphoto.jpg
  oldjunk.txt
  oldfolder/
    oldfile.txt
  newpage.html
  newimg.png
```

There's now ~1800 files in the root. My FTP client is slow to retrieve directory listing, so managing the website is difficult.

I'd like to tidy this up. I know which files I *want* to be stored at root-level (new stuff). Everything else, I've moved into a `legacy/` folder.

```
/
  legacy/
    oldphoto.jpg
    oldjunk.txt
    oldfolder/
      oldfile.txt
  newpage.html
  newimg.png
```

Problematically: some of those old files are still accessed today, from various external websites.

I want to make a cunning mod_rewrite rule that works like this:

> file didn't exist?
>   okay, does it exist in the legacy/ folder?
>   then, I'll redirect you to the appropriate file in the legacy/ folder

So the following cases need to work:

```
#[A] file does not exist in /, exists in legacy folder: redirect
http://example.com/oldphoto.jpg -> http://example.com/legacy/oldphoto.jpg

#[B] file does not exist in /, exists in legacy folder: redirect
http://example.com/oldfolder/oldfile.txt -> http://example.com/legacy/oldfolder/oldfile.txt

#[C] file does not exist in /, does not exist in legacy folder: 404 as usual
http://example.com/not-exist.txt -> 404

#[D] file exists in /: serve page as usual
http://example.com/newpage.html -> http://example.com/newpage.html
```

I got pretty close to getting this working:

```
RewriteEngine on

# No such file exists:
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
# No such directory exists:
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

# Capture the head of REQUEST_URI into %2 backreference; this tells us the absolute path to our web root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^(.*?)::(.*)\1$

# File exists web_root/legacy/REQUEST_URI OR
RewriteCond %2/legacy/%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
# Directory exists web_root/legacy/REQUEST_URI OR
RewriteCond %2/legacy/%{REQUEST_URI} -d

# Redirect to /legacy/REQUEST_URI
RewriteRule .* /legacy/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But this only solves cases A,C, and D. The nested case (B) fails, because `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` is not what I thought it was.

I am testing the redirect like so:

```
curl -sI 'http://example.com/oldphoto.jpg' | grep Location | sed 's/^Location: //'
http://example.com/legacy//oldphoto.jpg
```

Here is what the macros expand to:

```
# when requesting 'http://example.com/oldphoto.jpg':
SCRIPT_FILENAME:  /customer/homepages/13/c12345678/htdocs/user/oldphoto.jpg
REQUEST_FILENAME: /customer/homepages/13/c12345678/htdocs/user/oldphoto.jpg
DOCUMENT_ROOT:    /var/www/html
REQUEST_URI:      /oldphoto.jpg
THE_REQUEST: HEAD /oldphoto.jpg HTTP/1.1

# when requesting 'http://example.com/oldfolder/oldfile.txt':
SCRIPT_FILENAME:  /customer/homepages/13/c12345678/htdocs/user/oldfolder
REQUEST_FILENAME: /customer/homepages/13/c12345678/htdocs/user/oldfolder
DOCUMENT_ROOT:    /var/www/html
REQUEST_URI:      /oldfolder/oldfile.txt
THE_REQUEST: HEAD /oldfolder/oldfile.txt HTTP/1.1
```

We can see that `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` does *not* give the full path to my file.
We can also see that `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` cannot be relied upon to give us the absolute path to my web root.

If somebody requests `http://example.com/oldfolder/oldfile.txt`:

- **how do I check for the existence of `/customer/homepages/13/c12345678/htdocs/user/legacy/oldfolder/oldfile.txt`?**
- **how do I redirect the user to `http://example.com/legacy/oldfolder/oldfile.txt`?**

I assume that `/customer/homepages/13/c12345678/htdocs/user/` is likely to change (I have managed web hosting), so I would prefer not to hard-code it.
I am surprised that `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` does not give me this. Maybe it gives logical web root instead of physical web root.

I am also surprised that `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` gives me `…/oldfolder` rather than the path suggested in `%{REQUEST_URI}`: `…/oldfolder/oldfile.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be over complicating the process. The process is simply:

- If the requested file does not exist, but does exist in the `/legacy` subdirectory then redirect.

This would seem to handle situations A, B, C and D. For C and D you don't actually need to do anything.

So, try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/legacy/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.*) /legacy/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This naturally only checks that a *file* exists in the `/legacy` subdirectory. Is there really a need to check for directories as well? I thought you were only moving "files"?

Change the 302 (temporary) redirect to a 301 (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK. Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing.

> We can also see that `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` cannot be relied upon to give us the absolute path to my web root.
>   :
>   I am surprised that `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` does not give me this.

Me too, something is *a bit off* here... this is precisely what the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` server variable should be returning: the absolute filesystem path to your web root (ie. the document root). In your output, `/var/www/html`, looks "normal". (If this isn't returning the expected value then many web applications will fail to work? Unless your environment is *mashing* something together before the server-side script gets to have a go?)

In order to get `/customer/homepages/13/c12345678/htdocs/user` it looks like your server is maybe using some kind of `Alias` to map files from a different area of the filesystem?!

If you do need to grab the filesystem path from `REQUEST_FILENAME` (same as `SCRIPT_FILENAME`) then you could perhaps do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^((/[^/]+){6})
RewriteCond %1/legacy%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* /legacy/$0 [R=302,L]
```

This grabs the first 6 path segments from the `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that my `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` is not normal, and for showing me how simple it should be. It did seem more difficult than necessary. I was unable to fix that. But your regex helped me to generalize the hardcoded condition, so it's a little easier to live with.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. If using `%{REQUEST_URI}` (which starts with a slash) the slash in the `RewriteCond` _TestString_ should ideally be removed (although Apache probably strips the additional slashes when resolving the filename).

Comment: I confirm that Apache does strip additional slashes when resolving the filename. so `legacy/%{REQUEST_URI}` works fine for RewriteCond's filesystem check. similarly, it's possible to use `/legacy/%{REQUEST_URI}` in the RewriteRule — results in a double-slash, but request is still understood.

Comment: "...results in a double-slash, but request is still understood." - Yes, if the request maps to a filesystem path. However, as you say, the double slash is still present in the _URL_ and so may not route correctly (depending on how URLs are being routed in the web app). (Apache is also not so tolerant in `<Location>` wrappers - that again deal with the "URL", not the filesystem path - mutliple slashes are not collapsed here.)